# Разделить объект на столбики

Tags: php, yii2

Я хочу разделить данные на 2 столбика в цикле `foreach`. Вот моё представление

```
<article class="rowFlex-col l-person-col">
    <div class="c-personCard">
        <div class="c-personCard-details">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $cat) : ?>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><?= $cat->title ?>: </dt>
                        <?php foreach ($cat->fields as $field) : ?>
                            <dd><?= ($field->id_disser == $disser->id) 
                            ? $field->text : ''; ?></dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Как это можно лучше реализовать в Yii2?

Comment: http://site-on.net/create/php/10-html-table-php

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<div class="c-personCard-details">
<?php 
$total = count($categories);
$median = (int) $total / 2 ;
?> 
            <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) : ?>
                   <?php if($key <= $median ): ?>
                    <dl>
                        <dt><?= $cat->title ?>: </dt>
                        <?php foreach ($cat->fields as $field) : ?>
                            <dd><?= ($field->id_disser == $disser->id) 
                            ? $field->text : ''; ?></dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                    <?php else: ?>
                         <!-- Here is another column -->
                    <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

Надеюсь поможет.